# Is it possible to specify a container image to use when deploying Azure Functions from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

When creating an Azure Function using the Azure CLI, you can set a container image to use, with `--deployment-container-image-name`, [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_functionapp_create).

[image]

Is it possible, using the highlighted "Deploy to Function App..." button or otherwise, to specify a container image when deploying a function in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run and deploy azure function in VS Code based on [this plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/blob/main/README.md).

You can check, so it doesn't have this feature. You can first create the function app by command, and then use azure function plugin in VS Code to deploy.